# get object data , load 2 condition the same time

Tags: javascript

```
var id = "displayImage1";
//my object 
var json = {
  displayImage1: {
    object: "style1"
  },
  displayImage2: {
    object: "style2"
  },
  displayImage3: {
    object: "style3"
  }
};

function JsonLoad(_id){
    checkImgCanvas = _id;
    for (var i in json) {
    if(i === checkImgCanvas){
        alert("yes got it");
    }else{
        alert("not object found");
    }
    }

}
```

i am using this function to check if any json object value match the id value , if yes load "yes got it" else load "not object found". i do get the match but it also load "not object found" 2 times , i have no idea why ? it should not load the else condition cause i have match in my json object.

how do i make this function if match load "yes" if no load else condition.(load once)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/v7rjdkj6/)

Comment: Replace the for loop with `if (_id in json) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your for loop executes even after you found your result, you are getting the "no object found" message. You should exit your loop once you found your desired result and to achieve that, you can use `break;` after your success alert message

```
function JsonLoad(_id){
    var matchFound = false;
    for (var i in json) {
        if(i === _id) {
            matchFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(matchFound) {
        alert("yes got it");
    }else{
        alert("not object found");
    }
}
```

Comment: the id will change depends what i need to check , if my id was displayImage2 it will load the "no object found" again. is there any other way if check matched dont load the else condition ?

Comment: Updated the logic in my answer, hope this is what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var json = { displayImage1: { object: "style1" }, displayImage2: { object: "style2" }, displayImage3: { object: "style3" } };

function JsonLoad(_id) {
    !Object.keys(json).some(function (k) {
        if (k === _id) {
            document.write('yes got it<br>')
            return true;
        }
    }) && document.write('not object found<br>');
}

JsonLoad('displayImage0');
JsonLoad('displayImage1');
```